# Cannot running next process when a variable save no value

Tags: php, mysql

First, I wanna compare between 2 tables `tb_wrapper` and `tb_summary` to get the data in the `tb_wrapper` that doesn't exist in the `tb_summary` then save in `$link`. If I don't get the same data, I want to print the result `$link`. When I don't get the not same data, I want it to go to another process.

Here's the code :

```
$q2 = mysql_query(" SELECT 
                          a.doc_url 
                    FROM
                          tb_wrapper a
                    LEFT JOIN 
                          tb_summary b
                          ON a.doc_name = b.doc_summ
                    WHERE
                          b.doc_summ IS NULL");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q2)){
    $link = $row['doc_url'];
    if ($link){ 
       include 'next_process.php';
    }
    else {
       include 'blablabla.php';
    }
}
```

it doesn't work. When I don't get the not same data or `$link` not save a value.

table :

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
(`id` int, `doc_name` varchar(100), `doc_url` varchar(50))
}

CREATE TABLE tb2
(`id` int, `doc_summ` varchar(100))
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a `SHOW CREATE` of both tables?

Answer (score 0):

Since your tables lack either `PRIMARY KEY` or any other `INDEX`, this query might take some time:

```
SELECT a.doc_url 
FROM tb_wrapper a
WHERE a.id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT tw.id
    FROM tbl_wrapper tw
    LEFT JOIN tb_summary b
        ON tw.doc_name = b.doc_summ )
```

Comment: my query gives me right result... it seems I made the wrong condition after while

Comment: From what I can see, your query will give the right result, i.e. you'll get a link in $link all the time. What's not clear is what you are testing for?

I ran a quick test and it prints out everything no problem. The **if** never runs.

Comment: maybe `if ($link==='')` would help?

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn I've edited my code. if all datas in `doc_name` (`tb1`) same with data in `doc_summ`(`tb2`) `$link` will save no value.. go to `blablabla.php`. and for that case, it doesn't work

Comment: @davidkonrad i've tried using `if ($link==='')` still same :(

Comment: What is happening in blablabla.php?

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn page result, some query to show data from database. the query takes data from 2 tables `tb1` and `tb2` and one another table. if I run page result directly, it runs well.

Comment: I don't think you can use $link in the included files; at least it doesn't work for me. Maybe you can run a test to see if the files are being called and if they can access $link.

I'd expect to see a funcion call, not **include(...)**

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn FYI, if i change `include 'blablabla.php';` with simple one `echo 'ok' ` it doesn't work too and get a warning `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1` It seems something not proper in `$link` ?

Comment: There's a space before your SELECT in the code above.

Can you change your code to something like this to see what's running?

if ($link){ 
       echo "if $link true: ".$link;
    }
    else {
       echo "if $link false: ".$link;
    }